# Listview gridview

Tags: php, listview, gridview

I have a site where i display multiple products which are dynamically populated and displayed b querying a database. The page uses php. For the life of my i cannot get a gridview and listview button to work using php variables...Basically i am populating the variables like this

I need to display the variables below using a gridview/listview set of buttons on the page...HELP!!!

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){


$distance = Dist ($row['latitude'], $row['longitude'], $zip['latitude'], $zip['longitude']);
if ($distance <= $r) {
$LAT=$row['latitude'];
$LONG=$row['longitude'];
$id_contactname=$row['contact_name']; 
$CATNAME=$row['catname'];
$date = $row['date'];
$PRICE=$row['price'];
$TITLE=$row['title'];
$zipcode=$row['zipcode'];
$ITEM_NUM=$row['idnum'];
$adphoto=$row['adphotos'];
```

$details= 
etc........

Comment: Hi Indrasinh, is this enough code? I really need to get this working...thanks

Comment: Not sure i understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok, so currently the output displays one record(product) per row.. I want to have an option to display either in a list mode or grid mode much like the way craigslist displays their items. Without refreshing the page

Comment: Example....http://www.vandelaydesign.com/list-grid-view-switch/

Comment: Have you downloaded the source code provided by craigslist?

Comment: I dont know how to implement with the php code i am currently using

Comment: No i did not download

Comment: I do not have photoshop...I just need to be able to display grid or listview using a grid/listview buttons..

Answer (score 0):

I am able to give you some idea how you can do it.
Download the source code provided by craigslist [here](http://vanfree.s3.amazonaws.com/jquery-list-grid-switcher-source.zip) and Check whether it works properly if so just edit it with some php code as mentioned below:

```
$result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $distance = Dist ($row['latitude'], $row['longitude'], $zip['latitude'], $zip['longitude']);
    if ($distance <= $r) {
        $LAT=$row['latitude'];
        $LONG=$row['longitude'];
        $id_contactname=$row['contact_name']; 
        $CATNAME=$row['catname'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $PRICE=$row['price'];
        $TITLE=$row['title'];
        $zipcode=$row['zipcode'];
        $ITEM_NUM=$row['idnum'];
        $adphoto=$row['adphotos'];

        echo '<li class="clearfix">';
        echo '<section class="left">';
        echo '<img src="'.$adphoto.'" alt="default thumb" class="thumb">';
        echo '<h3>Product Name</h3>';
        echo '<span class="meta">Product ID: '.$ITEM_NUM.'</span>';
        echo '</section><section class="right"><span class="price">'.$PRICE.'</span><span class="darkview"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="firstbtn"><img src="images/read-more-btn.png" alt="Read More..."></a><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/add-to-cart-btn.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a></span></section></li>';
    }
}
$drop= "DROP table tmp_questions1";
mysql_query("$drop");
```